# MSA70 Upgrade options

Tags: storage, hp-smart-array, upgrade, hp-storageworks

Recently I purchased MSA70. Unfortunately I did read specs properly.
In my project, I need as much I/O operations as possible.
MSA70 is only 3Gbps, so my question is: is it any possibility to upgrade it to 6gbps, by replacing/adding better controller to pcie slots maybe?

Comment: IOPs is not the same as bandwith. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759571/iops-versus-throughput) for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no upgrade option with your existing hardware.

- If you need 6Gbps, locate an HPE StorageWorks D2700 enclosure.
- If you need 12Gbps, locate an HPE StorageWorks D3700 enclosure.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.